# Find which tiles are currently visible in the viewport of a Google Maps v3 map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build support for tiled vector data into some of our Google Maps v3 web maps, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to find out which 256 x 256 tiles are visible in the current map viewport. I know that the information needed to figure this out is available if you create a google.maps.ImageMapType like here: [Replacing GTileLayer in Google Maps v3, with ImageMapType, Tile bounding box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915944/replacing-gtilelayer-in-google-maps-v3-with-imagemaptype-tile-bounding-box), but I'm obviously not doing this to bring in traditional pre-rendered map tiles.

So, a two part question:

1. What is the best way to find out which tiles are visible in the current viewport?
2. Once I have this information, what is the best way to go about converting it into lat/lng bounding boxes that can be used to request the necessary data? I know I could store this information on the server, but if there is an easy way to convert on the client it would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, with help from the documentation (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html, especially the "Map Coordinates" section) and a number of different sources:

```
function loadData() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds(),
        boundingBoxes = [],
        boundsNeLatLng = bounds.getNorthEast(),
        boundsSwLatLng = bounds.getSouthWest(),
        boundsNwLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(boundsNeLatLng.lat(), boundsSwLatLng.lng()),
        boundsSeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(boundsSwLatLng.lat(), boundsNeLatLng.lng()),
        zoom = map.getZoom(),
        tiles = [],
        tileCoordinateNw = pointToTile(boundsNwLatLng, zoom),
        tileCoordinateSe = pointToTile(boundsSeLatLng, zoom),
        tileColumns = tileCoordinateSe.x - tileCoordinateNw.x + 1;
        tileRows = tileCoordinateSe.y - tileCoordinateNw.y + 1;
        zfactor = Math.pow(2, zoom),
        minX = tileCoordinateNw.x,
        minY = tileCoordinateNw.y;

    while (tileRows--) {
        while (tileColumns--) {
            tiles.push({
                x: minX + tileColumns,
                y: minY
            });
        }

        minY++;
        tileColumns = tileCoordinateSe.x - tileCoordinateNw.x + 1;
    }

    $.each(tiles, function(i, v) {
        boundingBoxes.push({
            ne: projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(v.x * 256 / zfactor, v.y * 256 / zfactor)),
            sw: projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((v.x + 1) * 256 / zfactor, (v.y + 1) * 256 / zfactor))
        });
    });
    $.each(boundingBoxes, function(i, v) {
        var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            map: map,
            paths: [
                v.ne,
                new google.maps.LatLng(v.sw.lat(), v.ne.lng()),
                v.sw,
                new google.maps.LatLng(v.ne.lat(), v.sw.lng())
            ]
        });

        polygons.push(poly);
    });
}
function pointToTile(latLng, z) {
    var projection = new MercatorProjection();
    var worldCoordinate = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
    var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(worldCoordinate.x * Math.pow(2, z), worldCoordinate.y * Math.pow(2, z));
    var tileCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.x / MERCATOR_RANGE), Math.floor(pixelCoordinate.y / MERCATOR_RANGE));
    return tileCoordinate;
};
```

An explanation: Basically, everytime the map is panned or zoomed, I call the loadData function. This function calculates which tiles are in the map view, then iterates through the tiles that are already loaded and deletes the ones that are no longer in the view (I took this portion of code out, so you won't see it above). I then use the LatLngBounds stored in the boundingBoxes array to request data from the server.

Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: Useful link for anyone else who stumbles upon this like I did: http://code.google.com/p/geotiles/source/browse/demos/cities_and_points/src/js/google-maps-v3-samples.js

Comment: @Nate - Awesome stuff.  Any chance you can add the code you used to delete the tiles that are no longer in the viewport?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific from which library did the MercatorProjection came and what is the value of MERCATOR_RANGE?

Comment: Hi @Ivan, it's been awhile and I no longer have access to this code. This may help though: https://gist.github.com/korya/ed5b859f93347c12593f0e1158860d67.

Answer (score 0):

For more recent users, it's possible to get tile images from the sample code in the documentation on this page of the Google Maps Javascript API documentation.

[Showing Pixel and Tile Coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates)